# How can I make my command more susceptible to system slowdowns so as to use it as a visual QoS widget on my desktop?

Tags: process-management, imagemagick, qos

I had some system slowdown event<sup>1</sup> after mistakenly using a command so I thought I could use a desktop "widget" to visually show *quality of service* or at least show when QoS was degraded and get some timely feedback. We have this natural ability to perceive degradation in the playback of an image sequence so I wanted to leverage this. Therefore I selected an mp4 video sequence<sup>2</sup> and made a .gif file out of a segment of it with [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html):

```
ffmpeg -i snf.mp4 -ss 00:01:24.0 -t 00:00:04.03 -s qcif -qscale:v 10 -an output.gif
```

So this will be a stamp size [qcif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Format) (176x144) gif image. In this example I extracted some 4.03 seconds starting at 1:24 into the sequence. Makes for a 1,3MiB file. Which I then [`animate`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/animate.php):

```
animate -borderwidth 0 output.gif &
```

Then I "float" that tiny window in my tiling window manager, and keep that handy. The sequence loops and if you click on the image you get an imagemagick ["display"](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/display.php)-like menu where you have that (beautiful)*auto-reverse* option... so the clip plays for its 4 seconds, then plays backwards and back and forth!

I thought maybe I could start this with `ionice -c 2 -n 0` (but there can't be i/o here really) or renice it with `renice -n -10` but i can't come to terms with how to "expose" this to "load" so that it would be the first thing impacted if there is a slowdown. From what I understand, if the execution is too nice, it should get impacted all the time but that wouldn't be related to a system slowdown, just to being "bumped". If it's not nice at all, then it wouldn't have to face any slowdowns unless in the most dire of states and that would defeat the purpose.

How can I set my command to be impacted *in priority*(as opposed to having or not having execution priority) to other programs on my desktop so as to serve as a QoS widget? Or is that just misguided and since load balancing is all about *heuristics* I won't be able to use something like that?

---

`ps aux` spec output for `animate`:

```
14454  0.3  2.9 228232 118768 pts/5   Sl   05:06   2:36 animate -borderwidth 0 test2.gif
```

---

<sup>1. I issued a wrong command using `convert`([ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick)) and it eventually exhausted system resources and self-terminated - I thought I was doing something legit so I let it go. During that time, I saw my system slowing down as the load increased; windows not refreshing, htop seemingly freezing, intense disk usage, and jerkiness with the mouse pointer. As the system was coming to a crawl, I noticed that looking at the movement of the pointer gave me a good "feel" of the slowdown so to speak. More so I found than looking at the load indicator reach 7-8 in my status bar(i3). Generally speaking for real time monitoring and information I use `htop` and the `i3 status` bar. But I'm also interested in different kinds of system feedback.</sup>

<sup>2. To help with my perceptual abilities, I selected a dancing clip. Some time ago I saw on youtube this famous dance sequence from *Saturday Night Fever(Bee Gees - "You should be dancing")* with *M. John Travolta* taking on the whole dancefloor. His landmark move is rythmic and the lights beat in a discernable pattern.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you're aware there are already a *lot* of system monitoring widgets. But anyway:

NOTE: Depending on your setup, there may be a dedicated hardware path for video. So its possible this doesn't really require any CPU time. But while ffmpeg may use that, animate probably doesn't.

NOTE: For your animation to slow down noticeably, it may have to be using a non-trivial amount of CPU time. That's going to make the CPU use more electricity and run hotter. If you have dynamic fan speeds, it'll make your machine louder.

First, *positive* numbers to nice are less priority, so you'd want to use 19 (the lowest priority). Second, there is actually a better option: you can change the scheduling policy, at least on Linux. There is a `schedtool` program that can supposedly do this (or you can use `sched_setscheduler` in C). If you set your policy to `SCHED_IDLE`, that is an even lower priority than niceness 19.

Note also that if your other processes are out of *memory* (i.e., your system is thrashing to death) then your animation may not notice first, as its not requesting memory. OTOH, a swap activity monitor will pick that up very quickly.

Finally, there are several ways to prevent runaway programs from making your system unusable: set a ulimit to prevent excessive resource usage, or use something like ulatencyd to automatically throttle them using cgroups.

Comment: @illuminÉ it's about general scheduling behavior. Some only applies to Linux (e.g., cgroups).

Comment: I see. I didn't know that setting things up like I wanted could potentially create a classic [priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion) scenario, although this is beyond me and I don't know how Linux's default scheduler deals with that. I read about the more recent [SCHED_DEADLINE](http://www.evidence.eu.com/sched_deadline.html) and something like I ask is not even conceivable with that. Seeing all that, I'm better off trying to influence the playback in some way by reading system values and not use scheduling for that purpose. Thanks again!